# combineReducers doesn't infer type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using `combineReducers`in my React TypeScript app:

```
// combinedReducer.ts
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import reducer1 from './reducer1'
import reducer2 from './reducer2'

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    reducer1,
    reducer2,
})

export default combinedReducer
```

I understand from [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#type-checking-reducers) that `combineReducers` should infer it's type based on the combined reducers.

However, for me it does not, even though each combined reducer has its return type recognised:
[image]
[image]
[image]

( `ReturnType<typeof combidedReducer>` is `unknown`)

**What is wrong here?**

Here are my maximally simplified reducers:

```
// reducer1.ts
const initialState: boolean = false

const reducer1 = (state = initialState): boolean => state

export default reducer1
```

```
// reducer2.ts
const initialState: boolean = false

const reducer2 = (state = initialState): boolean => state

export default reducer2
```

Comment: That's not Redux that's having a problem with it. That's your IDE/Editor. Technically speaking combineReducer can return anything, so it's return value isn't specifically typed. What ever editor you're using is looking at that signature and trying to interpret it.Seeing that combineReducers doesn't return a specific type, it reports back to you that it's "unknown".  I don't think it has anything to do with  Redux. Based on the color scheme, looks like IntelliJ? Yeah, I've had issues with it too,so I use VSCode for all the front end stuff, it seems to deal with it better

Comment: Well, take a look at redux documentation: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#type-checking-reducers

They're using `createReducer` like I do, but they get the return type as `RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>`. When I do that, I get `<unknown>`.

It's not just IDE, I can't run my code because tslint is complaining. AFAIK IDE takes its information from there too.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `combineReducers` gathers multiple reducer functions **named identically to the global store properties they're intended to modify**

Answer (score 3):

Same problem for me using redux 4.0.5 and typescript 4.0.1. Had to write a inferrer myself:

```
type BaseReducerMap<S> = {
    [K in keyof S]: (state: S[K], action: any) => S
}

export type InferRootState<ReducerMap extends BaseReducerMap<S>, S = any> = {
    [K in keyof ReducerMap]: ReturnType<ReducerMap[K]>
}
```

Then for your set of reducers (before you combine them)

```
const reducers = {
    login: loginReducer,
    chatUsers: chatUsersReducer,
};
const combinedReducer = combineReducers(reducers);

export type State = InferRootState<typeof reducers>;
```

Then typescript can successfully infer the type of my `State`.
I don't know why it fails in this version.

Comment: Wow thanks! That is some serious typescript-fu. Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Redux is at version 4.0.0 or higher. The type mappings for combineReducers was released with version 4.0.0, [here's the related PR on the redux github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/2182).

You can update your package.json file:

```
...
"dependencies": {
   "redux": "^4.0.3"
}
...
```

Then run npm install to update to the latest version.

Once you've made this change, make sure you restart your IDE to reload the type mappings.